# Decorator function

Tags: python, python-3.x

My decorator function doesn't work. The decorator function does not seem to receive the decorated function automatically.

This is the error displayed in the terminal:

```
TypeError: Browser.check_if_logged() missing 1 required positional argument: 'function'
```

This is my code:

```
def check_if_logged(self, function) -> bool:
'''
Decorator class that verify if user is logged or not.\n
IF user IS NOT logged, then execute login on ERP\n
IF user IS logged, then pass.
"
'''
    def wrapper():
        try: 
            if self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[text()="Login administrativo"]'):
                function()
                return True
            else:
                if self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[text()="Selecione uma empresa"]'):
                pass
            except Exception as e:
                print('Houve um erro ao validar login:', e)
                return False

            return wrapper()


@check_if_logged
def to_do_login_erp(self):
    try:
        input_login = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, ERP_INPUT_LOGIN_USERNAME)
        input_login.send_keys(USER_NAME_LOGIN)
        input_password = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, ERP_INPUT_LOGIN_PASSWORD)
        input_password.send_keys(PASSWORD_LOGIN)
        btn_login = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, ERP_BTN_LOGIN)
        btn_login.click()
    except Exception as e:
        print('Erro ao realizar login: ', e)
```

Comment: (1) "self" as parameter should only be used for methods in a class. (2) Fix the indentation of the shown code.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not stated very clearly, but I would assume that those two functions are in some class.

The problem is that you create a wrapper inside the class. Your wrapper `check_if_logged` expects two arguments `self` and `function`. When you use it as wrapper `@` you give only one argument to the function `check_if_logged` (this argument is `to_do_login_erp`). It doesn't get the `self` from the class, even though it is defined there. That is why you need to create wrappers outside the class.

One other thing that might come up later: your `function` needs to be returned and not called (so not `function()`). The wrapper looks normally like this:

```
def check_if_logged(function):
    def wrapper():
        check_something()
        return function
    return wrapper()
```

For your purposes I would not use the wrapper, and just directly make a check_if_logged in the function I want to call, because you as well want to use some properties or functions of your class to check if you are logged.

Hope this could help.